# Why does English only have one form of we/us?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, personal-pronouns

I have tried googling this and looking here to no avail. Why does English only have one we? What I mean is, why aren't there two forms for:

- Me and someone else excluding you
- Me and someone else including you

Comment: None of the other languages that English is closely related to, like German or French, make this distinction either, as far as I know.

Comment: Just keeping objective and subjective straight is hard enough -- no sense in adding even more complexity.

Comment: Old English did have a distinction I = **ic**; we two = **wit**; we = **we** but it was lost in Middle English as there seemed to be no useful purpose for it. The loss might also have be related to the introduction of Norman French, which did not have this distinction. The other point is that English has developed sufficiently to be able to exist well without such a form of pronoun as the idea can be expressed in other ways.

Comment: What is your native language? I assume that it has the forms of "we" that you describe.

Comment: @Greybeard [Yit](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED53969) might also want to think about the lost second person counterpart too.

Comment: It would help if you gave us two sentences to illustrate the difference. You could leave a blank where the words would go and we can tell you how to express the difference in English.  I suspect we would use "you and I/me" or "He and I/ him and me"  Also the context will make a difference as in, "**We** will tell **you**"

Comment: Most languages in the world do not feature "clusivity" - a grammatical distinction between inclusive and exclusive first-person pronouns.  Almost all austronesian languages do, as do a large number of indigenous American languages, Dravidian languages and a handful of others.  The only Indo-European languages (Indo-European being the group of languages English belongs to) that include this feature are ones that are spoken in India, where previously people spoke Dravidian languages - i.e. they inherited clusivity from Dravidian.

Comment: This is a good question, but it might be better on Linguistics. Very few languages make this distinction, and those that do, typically don't make *only* this distinction, but also a whole bunch of others to supplement it.

Comment: English is missing lots of distinctions that some other languages have, we usually resolve the ambiguities either through context or adding extra words to clarify. Language evolution is mostly circumstantial, it's hard to give specific "reasons" why things happened.